# Error: POST http://localhost:3001/undefined/api/news/getNewsByCategoryId 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

When I'm trying to post content from ADMIN to USER, I'm getting a 404 error.

> Error :
> xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:3001/undefined/api/news/getLatestImageNews 404 (Not Found)
> xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:3001/undefined/api/news/getNewsByCategoryId 404 (Not Found)
> xhr.js:177 GET http://localhost:3001/undefined/api/category/getAll 404 (Not Found)

News.js

```
const news = {
    api: {

        getNewsByCategoryId: (data) => 
            axios.post(CONSTANTS.API_URL + CONSTANTS.NEWS_URL + CONSTANTS.GET_NEWS_BY_CATEGORY_ID, data, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            }).then(res => res)
```

Category.js

```
class Category extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            videos: [],
            message: null,
            showButton: true,
            item: null,
            showItem: false,
            index: 0,
            newList: [],
            id: null

        }
        console.log(this.props.match.params.id)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            id: this.props.match.params.id
        },() => {this.getVideos(0, 10);})
        
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if(nextProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id){
            this.setState({
                id: this.props.match.params.id
            },() => {this.getVideos(0, 10);})
        }
    }

    getVideos = (skip,limit) => {
        let data = {
            skip: skip,
            limit: limit,
            id: this.state.id,
        }
        NEWS.api.getNewsByCategoryId(data).then(res => {
            if(res.status === 200){
                let list = res.data.data;
                let a = this.state.videos;
                if(list.length){
                    let e = a.concat(list)
                    this.setState({
                        videos: e
                    })
                }else if(list.length === 0){
                    this.setState({
                        showButton: false,
                        message: "No more news present to Load"
                    })
                } else{
                    this.setState({
                        message: "list is empty or failed to get List"
                    })
                }          
            }else if(res.status === 500) {
                this.setState({
                    message: "server error occured while getting Data"
                })
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            this.setState({
                message: "error occured"
            })
        })
    }
```

constants.js

```
export const API_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL +'/api';


export const GET_NEWS_BY_CATEGORY_ID = '/getNewsByCategoryId';
export const GET_NEWS_BY_CATEGORY_NAME = '/getNewsByCategoryName';
```

Comment: Seems `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL` is `undefined`. What is it supposed to be?

Comment: it is REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3000

Comment: Well, just look at your request URLs, ***something*** is undefined between `http://localhost:3001` and `/api`. Note also this is an entirely different port number. Try just hardcoding a proper/correct request URL to ensure your API endpoint is reachable.

Comment: @sindhujareddy if REACT_APP_API_URL=localhost:3000 then why in the errors port is 3001, error message must also have port 3000. We can only help if you share the correct information. As Drew said there is something left as undefined between your base url (localhost:3001) and /api.